# Kali Linux in VirtualBox (Windows 11 Host) Cannot Ping google.com but ping -4 Works

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, dns

I am seeking assistance with my `Kali Linux` virtual machine setup in `VirtualBox` hosted on a `Windows 11` system. I have configured my VM with a `network bridge`, but I'm unable to `ping google.com` normally. All packets are lost when I attempt to ping without specifying the IP version, but when I use `ping -4 google.com`, it works, indicating IPv4 connectivity is functional.
I use WI-fi for my internet connection.

I've taken the step of permanently disabling my firewall on the host to prevent any additional complications.

Here are the relevant configurations and outputs from my systems:

**Windows 11 Host:**

`ipconfig`:

```
Configuration IP de Windows


Carte Ethernet Ethernet 2 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte Ethernet Ethernet 3 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::6ed9:750c:6684:c6f3%3
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.56.1
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 2 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 4 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte réseau sans fil Wi-Fi :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:9dab:79da:e649:8ce4
   Adresse IPv6 temporaire . . . . . . . .: 2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:b14c:447e:b764:2aeb
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::1f84:f1a0:233d:bd6a%4
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.0.17
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:d4ff:feb9:cfa5%4
                                       192.168.0.254

Carte Ethernet Connexion réseau Bluetooth :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte Ethernet Ethernet :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
```

**Kali Linux VM Configuration:**

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:4a:2c:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 98  bytes 26962 (26.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 70  bytes 19343 (18.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 27  bytes 1524 (1.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27  bytes 1524 (1.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     30     0        0 lo
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.254
```

The above configuration seems correct to me, but pinging with IPv6 appears to be non-functional. I have encountered several forum threads and discussions online but have not found a solution that resolves my issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can provide insights into what might be going wrong?

---

**EDIT: Test for IPv6.**

My Internet router seems to have IPv6:

```
Router Ip adress: 192.168.0.254
Your prefix IPv6 : 2a01:0e0a:0ac2:81e0::/64
```

`ip addr`:

```
: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:4a:2c:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:f194:29ed:e11c:6b1f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86154sec preferred_lft 85833sec
    inet6 2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86154sec preferred_lft 86154sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`traceroute -6 google.com`:

```
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:4007:813::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

`nslookup -query=AAAA google.com`:

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4007:813::200e
```

`route -n -A inet6`:

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref  Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    30  2      0 lo
2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0::/64         ::                         U    100 2      0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    1024 2      0 eth0
::/0                           fe80::224:d4ff:feb9:cfa5   UG   100 5      0 eth0
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   5      0 lo
2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e/128 ::                         Un   0   3      0 eth0
2a01:e0a:ac2:81e0:f194:29ed:e11c:6b1f/128 ::                         Un   0   4      0 eth0
fe80::a00:27ff:fe4a:2c8e/128   ::                         Un   0   3      0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 6      0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1      0 lo
```

Comment: Bridging a WiFi *station* (not AP) does not "naturally" work but requires "tricks" in the hypervisor, because sending Ethernet frames with source MAC address different from the one used for WiFi association would break the association (at least when your are using an encrypted WiFi). I don't know what exactly is the cause, but I also saw very similar reports before. Probably it's some bug in VirtualBox.

Comment: @xenos92 You seem to not have IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: @TomYan Do you know how I can solve my problem ?

Comment: You need to add the output of `route -n -A inet6`, you also need to see if you can ping6 your local router.

Comment: @Bib I edited with `route -n -A inet6`